# Ocultar ou Exibir div por meio de um RadioButton via Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Segue o código abaixo:

HTML:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="rbAtivoInativo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true"> <%--OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbAtivoInativo_SelectedIndexChanged"--%>
     <asp:ListItem Value="ATIVO" Selected="True">Sim</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="INATIVO">Não</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Queria que quando o RadioButton com a valor INATIVO fosse selecionado aparece-se uma div que está oculta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito Obrigado pela resposta, mas já consegui resolver.
Segue o código caso alguém um dia precise.

```
 $("#rbAtivoInativo input").click(function () {
    var select = $(this).val();
    if (select == "INATIVO") {
        $("#cphConteudo_divMotivoInativacao").show();
    } else {
        $('#cphConteudo_divMotivoInativacao').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Via jQuery?

## Solução

Primeiramente importar o jQuery, colocando-o no *head* do arquivo. Após, criar uma *div* e defini-la inicialmente como `display: none;` na folha de estilo. Após, adicionar a interatividade (dentro de um `<script>`): quando for clicado *tal*, visível. Se *tal2*, invisível. Exemplo:

```
$('input#ativo').change(function(){
    $('div#alvo').fadeIn();
});

$('input#inativo').change(function(){
    $('div#alvo').fadeOut();
});
```

`fadeIn` e `fadeOut` podem ser tranquilamente substituídos por `show` e `hide`.

#### Criei um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQde4/)

Desculpe se não foi o pedido. Não conheço o *asp*, todavia sim *PHP* e *jQuery*.

Comment: Só alterar na sua resposta 'input#ativo' e 'input#inativo' para 'input#rbAtivoInativo'. O resto tá certo.

Comment: Não foi esta minha colocação.